# Trouble passing an array created by foreach into JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using Stripe to handle client payments and maintain subscriptions (side note, it's amazing). I need to list a customer's subscriptions in my webpage and I need to assume they can have up to 300 subscriptions (basically unlimited). I created some code in PHP that succesfully queries Stripe for a customer's subscriptions but only the the last (in this case the fifth on the test account) subscription is being sent through the JSON.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$custsubs = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customerID)->subscriptions->all(array(
      'limit'=>300));

               $i = 1;

               foreach ($custsubs['data'] as  $row){
                $rows= '<tr></td><td>'.$row['plan']['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['metadata']['Cust_Info'].'</td><td>$'.(($row['plan']['amount'])/100).'</td><td>'.$row['plan']['interval'].'ly</td><td>
                <div style="text-align:right" id="setdefaultplan'.$i.'" name="setdefaultplan'.$i.'"> <button class="button btn-blue" type="button" id="defplan'.$i.'" ><i class="fa fa-level-down"></i> Change </button></div></td><td>
                <div style="text-align:right" name="remplan'.$i.'" id="remplan'.$i.'"> <button class="button btn-red" type="button" id="removeplan'.$i.'" ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-ban"></i> Cancel Plan </button></div></td></tr>';
               $i++;
                               }
               $results = array('error' => false,               
                    'rows' => $rows
                    );
                echo json_encode($results);
                die();
```

The JSON result looks like:

```
{"error":false,"rows":"<tr><\/td><td>Monthly DIY Web Portal Access<\/td><td>Test Info<\/td><td>$6.95<\/td><td>monthly<\/td><td>\r\n\t\t\t\t<div style=\"text-align:right\" id=\"setdefaultplan5\" name=\"setdefaultplan5\"> <button class=\"button btn-blue\" type=\"button\" id=\"defplan5\" ><i class=\"fa fa-level-down\"><\/i> Change <\/button><\/div><\/td><td>\r\n\t\t\t\t<div style=\"text-align:right\" name=\"remplan5\" id=\"remplan5\"> <button class=\"button btn-red\" type=\"button\" id=\"removeplan5\" ><i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-ban\"><\/i> Cancel Plan <\/button><\/div><\/td><\/tr>"}
```

I pass res.rows into JQuery to make it neatly render inside an HTML table, but I don't understand why I am only getting the 5th instance in the foreach loop. How do I make it so I get them all sent throw res.rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never store `$rows` into the array until **AFTER** the loop completes, so you only ever store the LAST row produced.

You want:

```
foreach(...) {
   $rows[] = ....;
        ^^---array append
}
```

instead, so you build an array of rows.

Comment: I just noticed that this introduces "," into my HTML I think because the JSON is separating each $rows in the array by a ",". Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: that's how it's supposed to be. if you want one solid chunk of html, then `$rows = $rows . $newrow` instead.